# Is it possible to use a while loop instead of a for loop?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

The problem is: 
Given a string, return the number of times "e" is in the string minus the number of times "a" is in the String. Ignore the case of the letters.

I was wondering if you are able to use a while loop instead of a for loop to solve this problem. I was also wondering if using just if-else statements would work. If they are possible, could someone show me how to do it?

```
 public int eLessA(String str){
  int E = 0, A = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    if (str.substring(i, i+1).equalsIgnoreCase("e")){
      E++;
    }
    if (str.substring(i, i+1).equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
      A++;
    }
  }
  return E - A;
}
```

Comment: as per syntax you are allowed to use loops, if else etc within a loop.

Comment: You can always replace a for loop with a while loop and associated counter variable.

Comment: In general it's safer to use a for-loop whenever there's a definite number of loops involved, as in this case of operating on a fixed-length string.  It minimises the possibility of entering an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course.

Any time you have a forloop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    //do something
}
```

You can do

```
int i = 0;
stringLength = str.length();
while(i < stringLength) {
    //do something
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a while loop instead of a for loop. The only difference when using the while loop is that you increment in the body of the loop.

```
int i = 0;
while(i < str.length())
{
    // Do what you want here

    i++;
}
```